# How can I store GPS and direction coordinates in EXIF data when geotagging photos on the Samsung S7

Tags: geotag

I am walking transects in the field for a research project and in addition to other GIS points I am loading photos as points into ArcMap using the Geotagged photos to points tool.

I have found that a Galaxy S7 smartphone is a great tool for taking the photos.
I notice however that the EXIF data from the photos I capture on my Samsung galaxy S7 has the GPS coordinates but that the direction field is empty. 
I know that the phone measures this information and that Google Maps makes use of it.

Does anyone any experience of forcing the phone to store both GPS and Direction when geotagging ?

Comment: Do you need more support? If my answer was helpful and answered your question, please don't forget to accept that answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Open Camera (http://opencamera.sourceforge.net) for exactly this feature on my Motorola Moto G 3. Just install (also available via F-Droid) and enable "Store compass direction" under "Location settings...". You can also enable "Show compass direction" and "Show compass direction lines" in the "On screen GUI..." menu to check the direction before taking a picture.

I then use the current beta version of GeoSetter (http://www.geosetter.de/download/) to visualise the pictures and their position / camera angle.